How to disable play on awake for Unity VFX graph effect?
I have a VFX graph U want to play upon collision and not on awake, but I cannot figure out why I am not getting the expected result.
Attempted solutions:

Delete "OnPlay" from Initial Event Name.
Set an event block and connect it to the "stop" of the particle spawner

public class MeleeWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VisualEffect meleeStrike;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        meleeStrike.Stop();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        meleeStrike.Play();

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            print("melee hit");
            
        }
    }
}


Could you share this effect via a Unity package? It could be on GitHub or somewhere of your choice, so I can test it.
